# How to save automatically for the user changes

Tags: c#, winforms

How to save automatically for a validation part in windows form,

For example in windows form page I have a tab control with name called validation if user make changes

i.e., checking the check box and changing the color box all the changes should save automatically without clicking on save  button?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: subscribe to every changed event and do the save. Problem is, this may not help the user. what if they entered something wrong and decide to close the form? you then have something saved that they didn't want to save. Having the user press save is a GOOD design and gives the user control over their actions and not letting the app do it on their behalf when they don't want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Auto save is much complex operation. Because it interrupts user activity while auto saving. one simple method for implementing auto save

1. Create one Timer and Boolean flag variables .
2. Start the timer when application get started.
3. Set the flag if any changes done by user activity.
4. Call auto save function frequently according to timer interval. if the flag is set then the complete application changes get saved and
   reset flag.

Answer (score 0):

You could add event listeners/handlers to those controls and upon any change, invoke your `Save` method wherein you save the contents of the controls.

Eg:

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)Gridview.Rows[index].FindControl("CheckBox1");
    string checkboxstatus;
    if (cb1.Checked == true)
        checkboxstatus = "YES";
    else if(cb1.Checked == false)
        checkboxstatus = "NO";
   SaveData(checkboxstatus); // or something similar where you send the  data to a method that will actually perform the save operation

}
```

Comment: but in design page dynamically added so how can I do it

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you even need a Save button if you save automatically? 
Second, you may want to look into "Dirty" checking for the form you are in to see if there were changes in the fields.

You can create your own library to check/implement this but there are also few examples out there: [First example](http://rayli.net/blog/programming/quick-and-dirty-dirty-checking-for-windows-form-c/) and [Second example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38756/Two-Simple-Approaches-to-WinForms-Dirty-Tracking).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as Mamta D has suggested except when your form is generated create a handler for each type of control and subscribe all relevant controls to the handler. After which you can handle the saving process.

It's hard to really suggest a foolproof method of doing this without seeing how your code is being generated, however I will give it a shot for you.

Forewarning - I'm at work and this code likely will have 'issues' as I cannot compile and test. Firing from the hip as it were. Also I haven't handled assigning your controls to a container or anything like that. You'll have to figure that out yourself.

There are a few ways you can create on the dynamic event handlers you can either do your 'logic' on creation, using anonymous delegates and handle events like below:

```
var cb = new CheckBox();    

cb.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => 
{
        // handle your saving logic here
};
```

Or you can do it after it's been generated and implicitly create a handler to process all checkboxes in the form within the same handler like below:

```
var cb = new CheckBox();
cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckedChanged);

private void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //handle your checking and saving logic here.
}
```

Now if you're concerned about where the data is coming from and it needs to be saved to a specific location, for example - each checkbox is tied to a 'product' and the checkbox designates where or not the product is still in stock, then you will need to dynamically apply a name with `cb.Name = "nameHere"` and make it meaningful so you can check it in the event handler.

Using the second example:

```
   private List<Product> _products = new List<Product>();
   _products.Add(new Product("Product_1"));
   _products.Add(new Product("Product_2"));


   //Before anybody gets antsy in their pantsy, I know the above is syntactically incorrect
   //It's for illustrative purposes only


    private void Generate() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _products.Count(); i++) 
        {
            var cb = new CheckBox(); 
            cb.Name = _products[i].Name; //make it something generic like above, it'll help you check it

            cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckedChanged);
        }
    }

    private void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var cBox = sender as CheckBox;
       if(cBox.Name == "Product_1")
           //handle business
    }
```

Now this is ugly (very) so if it offends some of your eyes I apologize - it's purely illustrative.

This allows you to handle your logic based on the name of the checkbox and process it accordingly. You can do the same in the second example - my suggestion if you need to differentiate between the checkboxes - but if all the logic is the same, the first option is cleaner.

Both options work and they both assume you have the ability to modify the creation code. There is a way to handle it through reflection/linq without having to handle adjust your creation code but if you're struggling with this it'd probably be better for you to understand the logic behind what's happening before taking "shortcuts".

Hope this helps, if I misunderstood the question my appologize. The above code won't compile for syntax reasons, but you can easily adjust it to make sure it does (only one spot needs fixing). It's dirty as hell but for the purpose of showing you what you need you need to do to check and handle saving logic on changes based on events fired from dynamically generated controls - it serves it's purpose well.

Goodluck